# How to use VisualGDB embedded C++ refactoring features in VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, embedded

I am using VisualGDB v5.1 with Visual Studio 2015 for embedded ARM development.

How do I use/activate refactoring features like variable renaming?

It must be somewhere as it clearly says that on their [web-site](http://visualgdb.com/?features=embedded)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After hours of head banging to the wall I found an answer which was so obvious..

You simply rename something and a little bulb appears with a suggestion to rename it everywhere:
[image]

It's a shame that usual Ctrl+R,Ctrl+R shortcut doesn't work.